# Issue with axios request

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, request

I am having issue with getting my axios request to work. I am following pattern shown me in one of the Udemy courses. Interesting thing is that I can console.log data, but I can't return data, and save it to a variable. Any help would be appreciated.
Have a nice day!

```
const get = async () => {
  const res = await axios.get(
    "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/list.php?i=list"
  );
  return res;
};
```

Comment: return `res.data` instead of `res`

Comment: I have tried that already :/ I am still getting pending promise.

Comment: How are you calling `get`, I mean is that this way `get()` or this way `await get()`

Comment: I was calling it without async before function name.

Comment: 1. you should return `res.data` like Piyush mentioned above. 2. I think you might need to check `cors` policy, it might be the reason that your response is getting blocked

Comment: The most interesting part is that I can easily console.log data from response. But it seems like I can't do anything more.

Comment: Can you post your code of the way you are calling get?

Comment: I am just writing: get();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`async` means your function returns an promise. Thats a basic fact

```
const get = async () => {
  const res = await axios.get(
    "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/list.php?i=list"
  );
  return res;
};

get().then(result => {
   console.log(result);
})
```

Read about it: https://javascript.info/async-await

However you do not need `async` in this case because `axios` is already returning an promise

```
const get = () => axios.get("https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/list.php?i=list")
```

Comment: I am getting undefined... I don't have any idea how to fix this.

Comment: @NietypowyInformatyk could you add your try to your post

Comment: ```
const get = () => {
  axios
    .get("https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/list.php?i=list")
    .then((res) => console.log(res));
};
```
And it is working just fine. But when I try do store data, things go crazy.

Comment: @NietypowyInformatyk i think you dont unerstand fully promises and arrow functions? in your arrow function you use brackets `{}` and in my example i dont. i did not forgot them. if you write an arrow function without brackets the expression on the right side of the arrow will be automatically returned. But if you write an bracket it will not automatically return that means that your function does not return anything. returning nothing means `undefined`

Comment: I can't get it work...   But I would really like to understand this. I think that I will take some adittional lecture. I will recap this topic.

Comment: check out the event loop: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0 he will talk about how javascript works. also an article about how arrow functions work https://javascript.info/arrow-functions-basics

Comment: @NietypowyInformatyk you need to understand that promises are an event that will happend in the future

Comment: Thanks! I mean - I know that promise is something that will happend in the future, but I am missing something. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi. I have managed to make it work :) Thank you so much for your kind help. Now I am much more confident with promises, and all that async stuff. All best - Bartek.
Ps: I will also post my solution, maybe it will help someone. 

`let data;
const getData = async () => {
  const response = await axios.get(
    "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/list.php?i=list"
  );

  data = response.data.meals.flat(5);
};

getData();

const printMeals = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i]);
  }
};`

Answer (score 0):

You should return res.data

```
import axios from 'axios';
    
    const get = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get(
        "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/list.php?i=list"
      );
      return res.data;
    };
    
    const print = async()=>{
      const resp = await get();
      console.log(resp);
    }
    
    print();
```